# Blocking queue ascending counting problem

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 producer threads and 2 consumer threads. The problem is the counting in the output/console. Every thread does only count the hamburger (burger) they make, how can i get the value to be as in the wanted output? I think the problem is in the producer class in value. I want to use blocking queue to solve this problem.

```
Output from console:
Kokk3 legger på hamburger (1) >> [1]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (1) >> [1]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (1) >> [1]
Kokk2 legger på hamburger (1) >> [1, 1]
Servitør2 tar av hamburger (1) >> [1]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (1) >> []
Kokk2 legger på hamburger (2) >> [2]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (2) >> [2, 2]
Kokk3 legger på hamburger (2) >> [2, 2, 2]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (3) >> [2, 2, 2, 3]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (2) >> [2, 2, 3]
Servitør2 tar av hamburger (2) >> [2, 3]

Wanted output instead:
Kokk3 legger på hamburger (1) >> [1]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (2) >> [1, 2]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (1) >> [2]
Kokk2 legger på hamburger (3) >> [2, 3]
Servitør2 tar av hamburger (2) >> [3]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (3) >> []
Kokk2 legger på hamburger (4) >> [4]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (5) >> [4, 5]
Kokk3 legger på hamburger (6) >> [4, 5, 6]
Kokk1 legger på hamburger (7) >> [4, 5, 6, 7]
Servitør1 tar av hamburger (4) >> [5, 6, 7]
Servitør2 tar av hamburger (5) >> [6, 7]
```

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(5);
    
       //Oppretter trådene
       Thread kokk1= new Thread(new Producer(queue), "Kokk1");
       Thread kokk2=new Thread(new Producer(queue), "Kokk2");
       Thread kokk3=new Thread(new Producer(queue), "Kokk3");
             
        
        Thread servitoer1=new Thread(new Consumer(queue), "Servitør1");
        Thread servitoer2=new Thread(new Consumer(queue), "Servitør2");             
        
        //Starter trådene
        kokk1.start();
        kokk2.start();
        kokk3.start();
        
        servitoer1.start();
        servitoer2.start();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    int value=1;   
    
    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            process();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void process() throws InterruptedException {    
         
        while (true) {
            queue.put(value);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" legger på hamburger " + "("+value+")"+" >> "+queue);
            value++;
            Thread.sleep(vente());
        }
    }

    
  //wait between 2 and 6 seconds
    public int vente() {
        Random r=new Random ();
        int min=2000;
        int max=6000;
        int result=r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
        return result;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    
    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                Integer take = queue.take();
                process(take);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void process(Integer take) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" tar av hamburger " + "("+take+")"+" >> "+queue);
        Thread.sleep(vente());
    }
    
    //wait between 2 and 6 seconds
    public int vente() {
        Random r=new Random ();
        int min=2000;
        int max=6000;
        int result=r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `Producer`'s value as `int value=1;`, so each `Producer` is keeping its own copy of `value`. Your wanted output shows that you want all `Producer`s so share a single `value`.

In a single-threaded application, this would be as simple as changing the declaration to `static int value = 1;`, but doing that here introduces a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

The easiest way around this is to use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). An `AtomicInteger` guarantees that only one thread can read/write the variable at a time, which eliminates data inconsistency. In addition, `AtomicInteger` also guarantees visibility to each thread, so you don't have to worry about `volatile`-ity.

**EDIT:** If you want a guaranteed order of insertion, you can put the atomic operation inside the enqueue operation (`queue.put(value.getAndIncrement())`), but that doesn't give you access to the element inserted for logging. For that, you need to perform all three steps (getting/incrementing, enqueuing, and printing) atomically which requires a static synchronized method.

You may need to refactor `queue` to be a static variable to make this work, or add a static `Object` to act as a lock on a synchronized block instead of making a synchronized method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final static BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private final static AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(1);

    // Other things...

    private void process() throws InterruptedException {    
         
        while (true) {
            insertValue();
            Thread.sleep(vente());
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void insertValue() {
        int insertValue = value.getAndIncrement(); // Gets value then increments it before another thread can access
        queue.put(insertValue);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" legger på hamburger " + "("+insertValue+")"+" >> "+queue);
    }

    // Other things...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried your example, the burger number 2 was made before burger number 1 by the producer thread @Elan Hamburger